# Nodemailer: How to properly send a html message "stored" in a file?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I would like to simplify sending html-messages with Nodemailer by using messages stored as html-files instead of "hard-coded" message strings. However, for some reason Nodemailer does not work as I would expect it to do.

The following code works perfectly fine (version with "hard-coded" message string):

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const fs = require('fs');

let htmlMessage = "";

// Retrieve message from file
fs.readFile("./Message.html", 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data)
  htmlMessage = data;
});

console.log(htmlMessage);

// 1.) Define "transporter"
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: ...,
  auth: {
    user: ...,
    pass: ...
  }
})

// 2.) Configure email
const email = {
  from: ...,
  text: 'This is a test! (Plain Text)',
  
  // html: htmlMessage

  html: '<div style="margin: 1em; padding: 0.5em; background-color: rgb(90, 168, 90); font-size: 1.5em; '
  + 'border-radius: 0.5em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> '
  + 'This is a test!'
  + '</div>'

};

// 3.) Send email
transporter.sendMail(email, (error, info) => { if (error) {
  console.error(error); } else {
  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId); }
});
```

However, if I change the message like this ...

```js
// 2.) Configure email
const email = {
  from: ...,
  text: 'This is a test! (Plain Text)',
  html: htmlMessage

  /*
  html: '<div style="margin: 1em; padding: 0.5em; background-color: rgb(90, 168, 90); font-size: 1.5em; '
  + 'border-radius: 0.5em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> '
  + 'This is a test!'
  + '</div>'
  */
};
```

... and replace the "hard-coded" string with this file ...

Message.html

```html
<div style="margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(90, 168, 90);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  This is a test!
</div>
```

... sending the html content does not work any more. I am only receiving the "plain text version". For some reason Nodemailer fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure htmlMessage is not empty at the time of sending

Comment: htmlMessage is not empty. I console-log it after copying the string retrieved from the html-file to it to make sure that it has the desired content and I am absolutely sure that it is not empty

Comment: Can you share the result of that log?

Comment: how are you reading the HTML file? if you are using the fs module it has a readFile function where you can specify the encoding. Make sure it is utf8. Example - 
`fs.readFile( '/message.html', 'utf8', () => {})`

Comment: I do use the fs module with "utf8"-encoding (as you can see in the first code block of my original post)

Comment: I have been sending not only HTML from a file but HTML templates processed with Handlebars to Nodemailer. So yes, I can confirm that it definitely works when you send it from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of a common beginner misunderstanding of asynchronous code.

In your code you did this:

```
let htmlMessage = "";

// 1.) Retrieve message from file
fs.readFile("./Message.html", 'utf8', (err, data) => {

  // 3.) Callback completes
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data)
  htmlMessage = data;
});

// ....

console.log(htmlMessage); // SHOULD show empty string

// 2.) Configure email
const email = {
  from: ...,
  text: 'This is a test! (Plain Text)',
  html: htmlMessage
};
```

As you can see, the code executes `1.)` then `2.)` then some milliseconds **after** you have sent your email `3.)`. You basically have sent your email before reading your HTML file.

What you need to do is:

```
let htmlMessage = "";

// 1.) Retrieve message from file
fs.readFile("./Message.html", 'utf8', (err, data) => {

  // 2.) Callback completes
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data)
  htmlMessage = data;

  // ...

  // 3.) Configure email
  const email = {
    from: ...,
    text: 'This is a test! (Plain Text)',
    html: htmlMessage
  };
});
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to read the flow of your original code you can promisify `fs.readFile()` and use `async/await`:

```
const util = require('util');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function foo () {

  // 1.) Retrieve message from file
  let htmlMessage = await readFile("./Message.html", 'utf8');

  // ....

  // 2.) Configure email
  const email = {
    from: ...,
    text: 'This is a test! (Plain Text)',
    html: htmlMessage
  };
}

foo();
```